# How to use Epos?

Tags: 10.10, sound, text-to-speech

When I installed `epos`:

```
sudo apt-get install epos
```

and try to use `say`:

```
say hello
```

the terminal says:

```
hello#######################################################################################################################################################T
Could not open localsound device, error 2
Client side error: Could not set up a stream
```

How can I configure this software to make it run correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason you need epos? I installed it just to see if I could help you, and I'm appalled at the lack of end-user documentation. I ran into the same trouble you did. A few forum posts suggested no other sound application can run alongside epos. Additionally, there is a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/epos/+bug/497993) for this problem. You should go add your voice.

Try `espeak` instead. It was installed on my system by default (leastwise I've no recollection of installing it).

```
espeak "hello world"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Epos** is said to be the best TTS program for Czech language so this question is relevant.

I had exactly the same error and couldn't find the answer anywhere so I sent email to the author of the program and he replied back that it may have been related to `/dev/dsp` device or some other kernel module lacking.

There is really no `/dev/dsp`in my fresh Oneiric system so I Googled and found out that **padsp util** can emulate it.

Simply start your **eposd** daemon via **padsp**:

```
padsp eposd --voice "violka"
```

violka - the best voice for Czech but you must install it separately and it should work. Works well in my case.